# How to convert the list dictionary from a column value into column in pandas df?

Tags: python, pandas, list, dictionary, multidimensional-array

I have different columns and some of the columns contain a list and that list contains a further dictionary. I want to convert that list into the column and I am not sure what technique would be the best...

Here is how my df looks:

```
Car      Year       Conv                                                       Cost
BMW      2001       [{'action_type': None, 'value': None}]                   2000
VW       2009       [{'action_type': 'landing_page_view', 'value':'50'}]       5000
```

This is how ideally i would like to see

```
Car      Year       Conv - action_type     Conv - value         Cost      
BMW      2001       None                   None                 2000
VW       2009       landing_page_view      50                   5000
```

Comment: one question: the lists in Conv column are actually different or is it a typo? one is a list of list of dict the other is a list of dict

Comment: yeah it was a typo... sorry I corrected it

Comment: @s_khan92 So each list contains only one dictionary or can they contain multiple dictionaries? What will be the output in that case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a quick and dirty solution

```
df['Conv - Action_type'] = df['Conv'].apply(lambda x: x[0]['action_type'])
```

Answer (score 2):

This works for me (supposing there is only one `dict` inside the `list`):

```
new = {}
for row in range(df.shape[0]):
    d = df.loc[row, 'Conv'][0]
    for k in d.keys():
        if 'Conv - ' + k in new.keys():
            new['Conv - ' + k].append(d[k])
        else:
            new['Conv - ' + k] =  [d[k]]

for k,v in new.items():
    df[k] = v

df.drop(columns='Conv', inplace=True)
df = df[['Car', 'Year', 'Conv - action_type', 'Conv - value', 'Cost']]
```

Comment: @s_khan92 isn't this what were you looking for?

Comment: Hi. Thanks. the other solution seems better for me. :)

Comment: Your welcome! sure it's more compact but lose in generality ;)